# Select with if statement return 'column does not exist'

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-11

**Database, application.**
PostgreSQL 11.4 (Ubuntu 11.4-1.pgdg19.04+1),
Dbeaver 6.1.1.

**What I need?**
Return right values.

**What I do.**
Here is part of code.

```
select
if(available_count < 5, "neni skladem", "na sklade") as availability
from
...
```

Return this.

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "neni skladem" does not exist
```

Where is the catch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors in your statement:

1. There is no `IF` in SQL, you need to use a `CASE` [expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)
2. [String constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) are defined using single quotes in SQL (`'`), double quotes are for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

```
select case 
          when available_count < 5 then 'neni skladem'
          else 'na sklade'
       end as availability
from ...
```